# length of formatted decimal

Tags: java, decimal

I need a Java code to find the length of a formatted decimal. Eg - 345.4 it should return 5
Since the value is formatted so it omits 0 from the value 345.40
It should be written using `BigDecimal`

Comment: Just let the formatter do its thing and see how long the String gets?

Comment: i haven't tried i am quite new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have you `BigDecimal`, you can convert it to a **plain string** using `toPlainString()` method. Thus, the `length()` method of the `String` class gives you the length of your BigDecimal.